# Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I need to increment the next highest character field upon an insert - e.g. if '007' exists, then next is '008'

I have a stored procedure:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT LPAD(CAST(MAX(Line_Order) AS SIGNED INTEGER) + 1,3,'0')
    FROM bill_project_lineitems 
    WHERE Item_Id = vItem;
END
```

Then I have this trigger:

```
CALL MaxLineOrder(new.item_id,@new.line_order )
```

Which I call *before*.

When I try to INSERT, MySQL complains: *1415 - 'Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger'*

So then how do I solve this problem?

Comment: You are not showing the full code, and what you describe is impossible. Also, you are confused about the terminology, and this makes things even harder. Thry showing:
1) ALL your code
2) COPY/PASTE the error

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I read again and MAYBE I undestood. (but why not pasting the full code?) The error is clear, You **CANT** return a resultset from a Trigger.

I **suppose** that you want to issue an `INSERT` and get a resultset. But you can't. So you should:

1. Move your `INSERT` into the Stored Procedure
2. `DROP` the Trigger
3. `CALL` the Procedure.

Stored Procedures can return a resultset (or even many resultsets), so this will work. I hope that this is what you want.

Comment: That is the full code (and full error message) - I'm doing this within Navicat, not command line or other means. Not sure if your suggestion will work for me. I'll have to think about this. Thanks

Comment: Not, it's not complete: the CREATE part is missing. There is no reason why this can't work. If you explain your doubts, maybe I or someone else can tell you more suggestions.

Comment: Well again, I dropped the trigger and am using a stored procedure as per answer #2 above - as per your suggestion. Is that not best practice?